# How do I modify a string with a file path using java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file path stored in a string show below:

> String str="D:/tools/program/abc.java"

and I want to convert it into this:

> str=D:/tools/program/

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Did you try `replaceAll()` method?

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Bad advice. This is a substring job.

Comment: @jlordo Nah, you can replace it with `""`. Instead of finding the index of `.java` and substringing to it.

Comment: @jlordo, I feel I don't need Ferari car to travel just a 2 KMs.. :)

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Me too. Just in this case the regex is the Ferrari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "D:/tools/program/abc.java";
str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: I would look for `File.separator` in the `substring` call to have it more OS-independent

Comment: @Raibaz That depends on how he got the String.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Path` methods:

```
Path file = Paths.get(str);
Path folder = file.getParent();
```

And if you want to convert it back to a String:

```
String folderStr = folder.toString();
```

Although the content will be based on your OS standard separator, so in the case of Windows: `D:\tools\program`.

Comment: Upvoted because using `Path` instead of searching for "/" in the String looks more OS-independent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method in the string class.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "D:/tools/program/abc.java"

str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "D:/tools/program/abc.java";
    String withoutFileName = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    System.out.println(withoutFileName);

}
```